# How to get closest Vertex value from Selected Feature by point Using qgis python

Tags: qgis, python, vertices

For example 
I have a point ( 0 , 0 ) 
And I have a selectedFeature 
How can I get value ( x , y ) of closest vertex from selected Feature by Using Python Console in Qgis 

image for example :

[image]